# Send WM_NCMOUSEMOVE and WM_SETCURSOR messages. How to fill parameters?

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to send aforementioned messages. The documentation says:

> WM_NCMOUSEMOVE. lParam. A POINTS structure that contains the x- and
>   y-coordinates of the cursor.

How can I create a lParam from this structure?

> WM_SETCURSOR. wParam. A handle to the window that contains the cursor.

How can I pass it?

> WM_SETCURSOR. lParam. The high-order word of lParam specifies the
>   identifier of the mouse message.

What is this identifier?

Comment: It's unusual to ever need to send those messages. They are generated by the system, and applications can handle them. What requirement led you to believe that you need to send them?

Comment: @IInspectable I'm using Qt together with winapi. There're a lot of specific things - that's why I need to send them manually.

Comment: Anyway, I found that casting a `hWnd` to WPARAM works. Also I found that **identifier of the mouse message** is a named constant that identifies the purpose of a message.

Comment: This sounds very much like you're digging your own grave. Just because you're using Qt doesn't mean you have to implement the same mistakes, like faking/replaying system messages. What problem are you really trying to solve here?

Comment: The last several weeks I'm trying to create borderless window (ala steam, visual studio, battle.net). I finally fully understood how to do this with winapi (yes, even the colored glow around the window like in vs!), keeping all ui functionality - minimize/maximize, aero snap, aero shake etc. Now it's time to apply my knowledge to Qt. It's no so easy - for borderless window I have to use 2 windows - one is win32 window and another one is Qt window which is resides above the first one. And in order to drag, resize I have to do all this weird stuff like manual message sending.

Comment: In other words: You want to implement a feature, where you can move a window by clicking it with the mouse, anywhere inside its client area. This is easiest done by handling the [WM_NCHITTEST message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618.aspx), and returning `HTCAPTION`. No additional code required.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Also resizing. But it's not so easy in Qt - I don't have an access to Qt's window `WndProc`. That's why I need to send messages manually. Fortunately I figured out that too. The only thing left (for now) - is how to pass `POINTS' as 'lParam'. But this is more for curiosity.

Comment: Qt doesn't implement a window procedure in the same way Windows does. In fact, most *widgets* in Qt do not even have a window of their own. Luckily, you don't need access to the window procedure or the window handle. Simply operate on the specific widget's public interface. A word of warning: Qt is extremely brittle. Throwing random messages at it will break, sooner or later. Not that Qt doesn't come broken already, out of the box, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider LPARAM and WPARAM to be just numerical values data types.

you can use the MAKELPARAM and MAKEWPARAM macros to create your own LPARAMs and WPARAMs and then pass them.

here is the detail about them:
MAKELAPARM : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632661(v=vs.85).aspx
MAKEWPARAM : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632664(v=vs.85).aspx

So, just the pass the appropriate values and it will return the LPARAM.
But when the documentation says : wParam. A handle to the window that contains the cursor. Then you can simply create a lparam like this:
LPARAM lparam = m_hWnd;  //where m_hWnd is a handle to the window.

otherwise you can specify the high and low to the macro and it will create the LPARAM and WPARAM for you.
And to pass POINTS as LPARAM simply do this:

```
POINTS pt;
pt.x = pt.y = 120;
LPARAM lparam = &pt;
```

Comment: I don't think that's how you pass `POINTS`, see instead [`MAKELONG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes you can pass them using SendMessage(),  not a problem.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant - the LPARAM is not a *pointer*, it is the struct itself.

Comment: I dont know what makes you think its not a pointer !! 
 WinDef.h defines it as :
 typedef LONG_PTR            LPARAM;

Comment: `LONG_PTR` is an integer type that is large enough to hold either a `long` or a pointer. It is *optionally* a pointer. You need to look at the API call itself to know how it's used. In this case the API doesn't say pointer anywhere, it says that the LPARAM *is the struct*.